# How to refresh label when using setInterval with ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I used setInteval to update my variable $scope.labelText on per second in controller.js, but the label binding this variable can not be refreshed synchronously. Is there a way to trigger a refresh?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$scope.apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) as follow

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
     $scope.labelText = "new value";
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this night.